# Grails: Can I store GSP's outside the application?

Tags: grails, path, render, gsp

I'm making a CMS using grails. I'd like users to be able to edit their GSP's dynamically online. For the safety of their modified GSP's, I'd like to save it somewhere else on the server, not within the WAR structure.

How can I load or reference the GSP from a different location?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2138997/74057

Answer (score 4):

I do not know exacttly, but, perhaps, this configuration properties will help you:

```
grails.gsp.enable.reload = true
grails.gsp.view.dir = /path/to/your/gsps // default 'WEB-INF/grails-app/views '
```

Comment: doc link - http://www.grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#makingChangesToADeployedApplication